# Access denied to mySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

So I've been trying to solve this problem for a couple of hours now. And I have to make something clear.

1. I can access the mySQL database from terminal using

   > mysql -u root
2. I can also access the database from mySQL workbench
3. My root user on mySQL has no password

Now my code online is pretty simple. It is PHP calling the mysqli

```
<?php
$database = "myDatabase";

// Create new connection
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", $database);

if ($conn -> connect_error) {
  die ("Something went wrong: " . $conn -> connect_error);
} else {
  echo "It works";
}
?>
```

Now I always get the error code

> Something went wrong: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

If I could get any help that would be greatly appreaciated. I've already tried to grant access but I think I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: The answer is somewhere in your mysql.ini.  You might need to turn on remote connection privilege for the root user or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_connect` may be interpreting the empty password as no password at all

> using password: NO

Either try to set a password for the `root` user, or create a new user with a password. And via Tripp Kinetics comment, make sure the permissions are set properly for the new user.